# Docker: Installing libraries on centos image

Tags: docker, centos, libraries

I'm new to Docker. I created the following Dockerfile and ran it:

FROM centos: latest
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

I received the following error/output:

root@GGNLABVM-JUPER6:~/docker_test# docker build -t test .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB

Step 1/3 : FROM centos:latest
---> a8493f5f50ff

Step 2/3 : ENV container docker
---> Running in e8e244c0c9d6
---> 07355d554b3a
Removing intermediate container e8e244c0c9d6

Step 3/3 : RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
---> Running in 68ad7f2f86e2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be much slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

How do I fix this problem?

FYI: I want to install other python dependent libraries after for my application.

Docker Info:
Containers: 25
Running: 3
Paused: 0
Stopped: 22
Images: 13
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 78
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
apparmor
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-72-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.859 GiB
Name: GGNLABVM-JUPER6
ID: KXDG:GL4E:MPNN:4LYS:UO6Z:RFEK:BI2H:MJSP:BIMJ:NASA:XAFR:CRN7
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

Docker version:
Client:
Version:      17.03.1-ce
API version:  1.27
Go version:   go1.7.5
Git commit:   c6d412e
Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      17.03.1-ce
API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:   go1.7.5
Git commit:   c6d412e
Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Experimental: false

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? For me it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only a problem for Docker? Can you install other stuff from repo's with yum? If not its maybe a network problem. And also can you copy the output from `docker info` and `docker version` in here?

Comment: Nope. Nothing with yum seems to work. I read about changing the ./etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file to uncomment the baseUrl. That doesn't seem to work either.  I get network timeouts:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30546 milliseconds')

Comment: Okay so your problem is a network issue in first line. First check if you have a connection and try something like `curl` on a website.